# react-native run-android Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Tags: android, react-native

```
apple@mosesdeMacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/sxtbdemo2$ react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/apple/Desktop/sxtbdemo2/node_modules (8ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'sxtbdemo2'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
 Required by:
     project :

 Try:
     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Comment: please format your question

Comment: would you mind selecting the answer as solved? thank you.

Answer (score 99):

It is usually a problem with your repositories in your gradle files.

for me worked to modify the build.gradle like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

so when you add google() it should work.

Comment: Confirmed. Had same issue, adding google() worked. I believe google repo should be there in the default settings.

Comment: Confirmed. It is important to highlight that the google() repository must be added to the buildscript.repositories section, not to the allprojects.repositories section.

Comment: 2017-12-14, this solution work for me! macOS + React Native 0.51 + Android Gradle 4.1

Answer (score 30):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'      
    }
}
```

Add `google()` inside `buildscript()` and Sync Project.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#apply_plugin