# React-native build failed with gradle:3.0.1 missing error

Tags: react-native

I am using 'react-native -init test' command to create a project, when trying to start the project in Android simulator by using 'react-native run-android' command, it failed by issuing an error:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'test'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar

I've checked the URL, it does exist but returns nothing. does anyone have similar problem before?

Comment: I think this link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446681/react-native-run-android-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-1

Comment: thanks, i will have a look. at the moment i have a work-around by commenting out 'buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"'